ObjectBox Admin in Docker - Not refreshing UI data when db data are CRUDed
I am using ObjectBox Admin in Windows through WSL (Docker in WSL, using objectbox-admin.sh)) and accessing a db file in Documents folder (shared with WSL).
From my Windows app I can access the contents in ObjectBox Admin (at localhost:8081) without problem, but when CRUD action takes place, the UI doesn't show the updated data that are in the boxes. Even page refresh (CTRL-R) doesn't help.
In order to solve this, I need to stop the docker container and restart it in order to reload the DB from the disk and then refreshing the page in the browser.
Is this the typical behavior for anyone else or it is just on my system ?
